# Having trouble in speeding up scroll animation using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have below code. What it does is when user scrolls up/down the contents of the div scrolls accordingly but smoothly. At the moment, the code works ok but the scrolling up/down animation is too slow. **How can I make it a bit faster?**

Below is JS code

```
function onMouseScroll (e) { 
  var detail = e.detail, 
      wheelDelta = e.wheelDelta;

  if (detail) {
    if (wheelDelta && (f = wheelDelta/detail)) {
      detail = detail/f;
    } else {
      detail = -detail/1.35;
    }
  } else {
    detail = wheelDelta/120;
  }

  scroll(offset + detail);

  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation(); 
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the speed at line 23. If you decrease the number, the speed increases.

```
detail = wheelDelta/120;
```